# Append instead of overwrite

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code that I'm working on, and I'm trying to append instead of overwriting the #preview div. I'm using JqueryForm plugin for jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#photoimg').on('change', function() { 
        $("#preview").html('<img src="load.gif" alt="Uploading"/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

        });
    });
```

I'm not really sure how I can achive that.

Later edit: I have this form:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>
```

When I browse and select an image the ajaximage.php verifies and upload the image and if succeed it will echo a message that is shown in #preview div. The problem is that its overwriting the div even if I use append.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close then:

```
$("#preview").append('<img src="load.gif" alt="Uploading"/>');
```

Here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

---

Edit: based on your updated question, it appears that you may need to dynamically create a target for the `ajaxForm` plugin to use.  Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#photoimg').on('change', function() { 
        $("#preview").html('<img src="load.gif" alt="Uploading"/>');
        // create a dynamic target that we'll add to #preview
        var $target = $('<div />').appendTo('#preview');
        $target.attr('id', 'preview-target-' + Math.ceil(Math.random()*999999));
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            // use the new target element's id for the ajaxForm target
            target: '#' + $target.attr('id')
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Heh... my favorite kind of question.  "How do I do *<insert-exact-command-name-here>*?"

Comment: I tried this before asking and didn't work. I edited the main post because I was not explaining the entire process.

Comment: The behavior described in your update appears to be how the ajaxForm plugin works.  Perhaps you should consider having another nested target element inside of `#preview`?

Answer (score 1):

jmar is right.

Here is fill-in example command for it as for future reference.

`$('#idoftarget').append('<div>new stuff</div>');`